# Нужен хороший "движок" для видеоигры.

Tags: разработка-игр, c++, движок

Доброго времени суток.

Я программист C++. Решил создать свою видео игру, но какой движок и где его найти, увы, не знаю. Я буду очень благодарен тому, кто посоветует "движок" и укажет сайт, на котором можно его скачать.

Comment: C# и XNA, зная C++ в C# сложно запутаться XD

**UPD** а вообще лучше для начала хотя бы 4 класса физики (уровень 9 класса)

Comment: Немаловажно ещё то, на сколько ты C++ знаешь...

Comment: Если вы - программист, то единственный вклад в разработку "видео игры", который касается вашей специализации - это и есть разработка движка. Все остальное - это отрисовка текстур, анимирование моделей, написание музыки, запись звуков, motion capture и т.д. Попробуйте indie версию unity и вы поймете, о чем я говорю.

Answer (score 4):

Очень советую **UDK - Unreal Development Kit**

Бесплатно, если прибыль от Вашей игры будет более 50000$ кажется, будете с ними просто делиться.

Прочитайте у них на сайте [UDK](http://udk.com/) все очень подробно, но на английском, я скачивал пробовал (для самобучения) и мне понравилось, но относительно сложновато.

Answer (score 1):

unity3d

Comment: @anunak, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю SDL2 хорошим началом. Может это еще не совсем движок, но все же, первые свои игры я писал на SDL2.

Answer (score 1):

[Unity, 5 версия выглядит превосходно](http://unity3d.com/ru/5)

Большинство инди разработчиков используют ее, конечно у тех, у кого имеются деньги, все же платная, но она того стоит, кроссплатформенность и сильные эффекты графики

Answer (score 1):

**[COCOS2D-X](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/)** - 
Если планируешь 2d игру то это лучший вариант.
Документации и уроков достаточно много,туториала для минимума на офф сайте хватит для начала

Answer (score 0):

У крайтека неплохой движок =), а вообще двиг кваки бесплатный и дума 3его, **да и подход у тебя к этому делу неправильный**...

**UPD**
Ogre3D - это больше графический двиг. Но знакомый когда-то его ковырял. Так что для начала вроде бы неплохой вариант =)

Answer (score 0):

Куда более интереснее было бы написать самому двиг ИМХО.

А если лень то посмотрите в сторону

1. [Open Scene Graph](http://make-games.ru/load/sozdanie_igr/igrovye_dvizhki/open_scene_graph/135-1-0-739)
2. [Maratis](http://make-games.ru/load/sozdanie_igr/igrovye_dvizhki/maratis/135-1-0-720)